# Why is it so slow to create records with a field that references a big value in F#?

Tags: performance, memory, f#, reference, record

In the code below that is executed as an .fsx script, the final line takes around 30 seconds to finish. I assumed that since records are reference types, the final line only creates records with a field that references an (immutable) large value, and so it should be very fast. Why is it slow and how can I fix it?

```
type BigType = { Big: Set<int> }
type CollectionType = { BigVal: BigType; SmallVal: int }

let b = { Big = set [ 0 .. 999999 ] }
let mySet = set [ 0 .. 50 ]

#time

mySet |> Set.map (fun x -> { BigVal = b; SmallVal = x })
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to notice here is that the order you define the fields in `type CollectionType = { BigVal: BigType; SmallVal: int }` makes a difference.  If you try:

```
type BigType = { Big: Set<int> }
type CollectionType = { SmallVal: int; BigVal: BigType; }
let b = { Big = set [ 0 .. 999999 ] }
let mySet = set [ 0 .. 50 ]
#time
mySet |> Set.map (fun x -> { BigVal = b; SmallVal = x })
```

Instead the time taken goes from Real: 00:00:34.385 to Real: 00:00:00.002.

NB: I was originally concerned that this behaviour could not be relied on and might change without warning; however as nasosev has found this behaviour is described in the [F# language specification](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) see section 8.15.3 of version 4.1 of the document.

Comment: Wow! So fields are compared in their definitional order. Is there any reason not to expect this behaviour to always apply? If not it seems like a great solution to me.

Comment: Apparently this behaviour can be relied on, so I will accept this answer. From the F# spec. See 8.15.3
If T is a struct or record type, invoke FSharp.Core.Operators.(=) on each corresponding pair of fields of x and y in declaration order. This method stops at the first false result and returns false.

Comment: This is the accepted answer, but there is a key point missing.  @Tarmil 's answer notes where the equality operator is being called (Set is a sorted binary tree that uses F#'s structural comparison).

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `Set` is implemented as a search tree, so in order to insert an item into a set, it is compared against some of the existing items. So there are indeed only small records created, but whole sets are being compared.

It's hard to tell what the best way to fix the issue is without knowing the exact problem you're solving. But if it is a requirement that each `CollectionType` value has a different `SmallVal`, then you can do as Scott suggests and implement custom comparison that only looks at `SmallVal`. You don't need a class though, you can do it with a record:

```ml
(* For records, you need to put CustomComparison in addition to implementing IComparable.
   And CustomComparison requires CustomEquality and its corresponding overrides. *)
[<CustomComparison; CustomEquality>]
type CollectionType =
    { BigVal: BigType; SmallVal: int }

    interface System.IComparable with
        member this.CompareTo(that) =
            match that with
            | :? CollectionType as that -> compare this.SmallVal that.SmallVal
            | _ -> -1

    override this.Equals(that) =
        match that with
        | :? CollectionType as that -> this.SmallVal = that.SmallVal
        | _ -> false

    override this.GetHashCode() = this.SmallVal
```

Comment: Thank you. For my case I do need to distinguish been values of CollectionType with the same SmallVal value but different BigVal values, but I would like the equality on BigVal to be referential rather than structural, Is this possible?

I did know that know records are compared structurally as the other answer mentioned, but I assumed that referential equality implied structural equality, so if the BigVal fields were referentially equal there would be no reason to examine them structrually. Do you know why that is not the case?

Comment: The thing is, for `Set`, you need not just equality but comparison. And you can't really do comparison by reference in .NET. So I think you have 2 choices. 1: Add a Guid to `BigType`, fill it with `Guid.NewGuid()` when you create a value, and implement a custom comparison on `BigType` that compares this Guid. The structural comparison on `CollectionType` will use this custom comparison. 2: switch from `Set` to `Dictionary`, which only needs equality and can be referential, but of course works with mutation so it may not be appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 3):

If you convert to an array first then it takes no time at all:

```ml
mySet |> Set.toList |> List.map (fun x -> { BigVal = b; SmallVal = x })
```

So the time that it take to create the records is insignificant. The reason it's slow is that the records are inside a set. Sets need to compare their items to each other as part of the implementation, to make sure there are no duplicate values. F# compares records structurally, by comparing their contents. So these records that are being compared contain very large sets that take a long time to compare. They are actually different records but the same set in terms of objects in memory, but the F# record comparison doesn't know that, and doesn't check.

Comment: Thank you. I did know that records are compared structurally, but I assumed structural equality was implied by referential equality. Do you know why it is isn't? (See my comment to Tarmil's answer for more detail.)

Comment: @nasosev Structural equality could be implied by referential equality for immutable data structures, but that's a performance optimisation that hasn't been implemented and may be slower in some cases. Sets don't just use equality but comparison, i.e. which of these two items is larger, so that it can arrange the items in a tree. So even if two items aren't equal there is still more work to do to place an item in a set.

Comment: I see. For my actual problem what I think I want to do is override the equality so that just the BigVal field is compared referentially and the SmallVal compared structurally. (The other answers suggested I override equality so BigVal is ignored, but I do need values with different BigVals to be unequal--this is one of the main reasons I have the BigVal field.) Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @nasosev Do you definitely need a set? If you just want a way to find distinct values once then using `Array.distinct` might be much faster: `mySet |> Set.toArray |> Array.map (fun x -> { BigVal = b; SmallVal = x }) |> Array.distinct`

Comment: Thanks, but yes I do want sets---my program essentially involves manipulating sets and applying typical operations like intersection and union to them.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the F# community.

I'm guessing that each new record is copying `b`, although since records are reference types by default, as you say, I'm not sure why that would be.

This approach is no faster:

```ml
let y = { BigVal = b; SmallVal = 0 }

mySet |> Set.map (fun x -> { y with SmallVal = x })
```

Using a class instead is much faster:

```ml
type BigType = { Big: Set<int> }

let b = { Big = set [ 0 .. 999999 ] }

type CollectionType(smallVal: int) =
    interface System.IComparable with
        member __.CompareTo other =
            compare __.SmallVal (other :?> CollectionType).SmallVal

    member __.BigVal = b
    member __.SmallVal = smallVal

let mySet = set [ 0 .. 50 ]

#time

mySet |> Set.map (fun x -> CollectionType(x))
```

This is not a complete solution, since there is a warning `FS0343: The type 'CollectionType' implements 'System.IComparable' explicitly but provides no corresponding override for 'Object.Equals'. An implementation of 'Object.Equals' has been automatically provided, implemented via 'System.IComparable'. Consider implementing the override 'Object.Equals' explicitly`.

Comment: The problem seems to have something to do with the `Set` collection type: `[ 0 .. 50 ] |> List.map (fun x -> { BigVal = b; SmallVal = x })` is almost instantaneous.